# is it possible not use a specific resid name? android programming

Tags: android

is it possible not use a specific resid name?

for example i believe the normal way is like this:

```
    MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(main.this, R.raw.abandon);  //abandon being the soundfile file name inside the raw folder
```

it is possible or is their a way to make like this:

```
    String string= abandon;
    MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(main.this, R.raw.string);
```

i would like the method above because im to use an inputted string to play a file on  the raw folder
sorry if its a bit messy..but i really need the help.tnx

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. Do you mean you want to be able to use any name in place of abandon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is store is as an Integer

```
int id= R.raw.abandon;
MediaPlayer sound = MediaPlayer.create(main.this, id);
```

The `R.raw.abandon` returns an id identifier of the resource. Which is used in the create method.

You can store this int to a variable of any name, and pass that instead.